# "Second order" widest path problem

Tags: graphs, weighted-graphs

Let's say we have a directed graph in which each *pair* of adjacent edges has a weight; or, alternatively, each ordered triple of vertices A, B, C has a weight $W(A,B,C)$ of going A->B->C.

I am looking for a generalisation of a [widest path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widest_path_problem) in such graph, that is, a way to find a directed path between given two vertices, which has a maximal minimal weight of an intermediate step.

The naive solution is to generate a regular, directed graph which vertices contain ordered pairs of vertices of an original graph, connected by edges with weights $\hat{W}(IJ,JK)=W(I,J,K)$, and this way lower the whole problem to standard widest path, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Unless you want to achieve something like $O(|E| \log^* |V|)$ complexity, I don't think your solution is bad: you don't increase size of the problem, and it still can be solved in $O(|E| \log |E|)$ time, where $|E|$ is the number of triples.

Comment: When looking the widest path, among all triplets $(A, k, C)$, there is no point to consider any other triplet than the "widest"one. Then you may generate a classical widest path problem in linear time of the number of triplets.

Comment: @Optidad Imagine a graph X->A->C=3, XBC=2, ACY=1, BCY=2; widest path X->Y is
XBCY, but this goes through XBC, which would be removed by the step you
propose.

Comment: @Dmitry Seems so... It inflates the vertex count, though, so a good data structure is a key.

Comment: @mmm Okay I may misundertood the question. Let's take a path ABCDE. The path width is min(W(A, B, C), W(C, D, E)) or min(W(A, B, C), W(B, C, D), W(C, D, E)) ?

Comment: @Optidad The latter.